# How to improve search by specific date function in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the information of events in database which have (events title, from_date, to_date)

```
events      from_date    to_date
events 1    2018-10-12  2018-10-16
events 2    2018-10-15  2018-10-19
events 3    2018-10-11  2018-10-17
```

And this is my search by specific date function

```
$from_date = Carbon::parse(request('from_date'))->endOfDay();

        $events = Events::where('from_date', '<=' ,$from_date)
            ->where('to_date', '>=' ,$from_date)
        ->get();


        return $events;
```

My route for this API is day-search. so when i input api/day-search?from_date=my input. When i input the 2018-10-15, it should be shown all 3 events occur during the 2018-10-15.

Is there anyway to improve the accuracy of this code? Thank you.

Comment: Your code looks correct to me.  Is it correct?  If not, what is the problem here?

Comment: when i search by specific date, test everything is good, but i dont know what is error in logical in here. That's why i want to find out the way to improve the search accuracy

Comment: When i run in the real project, this code is only return 1 record. I dont know which one is wrong

Comment: Can you include the value of `$from_date` when you ran the above PHP code?  When you get stuck like this, a good idea is to always go back to the raw MySQL query and make sure everything works there with your data.

Comment: i have improved the accurracy of the query. Means i forgot that there is startOfDay and endOfDay. I have added for checking always in range of Day.